# Unable to get poller added to view interface details using SNMPv3 on Solarwinds

Tags: python, snmpv3

I am unable to get the poller added to view interface details using SNMPv3 on Solarwinds. I am using the following pollers:

```
'N.Status.ICMP.Native': True,
'N.Status.SNMP.Native': False,
'N.ResponseTime.ICMP.Native': True,
'N.ResponseTime.SNMP.Native': False,
'N.Details.SNMP.Generic': True,
'N.Uptime.SNMP.Generic': True,
'N.Cpu.SNMP.HrProcessorLoad': True,
'N.Memory.SNMP.NetSnmpReal': True,
'N.AssetInventory.Snmp.Generic': True,
'N.Topology_Layer3.SNMP.ipNetToMedia': True,
'N.Routing.SNMP.Ipv4CidrRoutingTable': True
```

The above pollers help me successfully to get node details such as "Machine Type", "System Name", "Description" etc. but unable to get the interface details for the node. In order to get the interface details, I have to click on "List Resources" and then Submit manually. Can someone let me know what's the correct poller to view interface details after adding nodes via SNMPv3?